# Deployment Manager not opening

Tags: marketing-cloud, deployment, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

I have installed deployment manager on SFMC account enterprise BU but it is continuously throwing the following error. Can anybody have an idea why i am getting this error.

error : mc9gph0gwn67-wz4y01.auth.marketingcloudapis.com refused to connect.

Thanks
R

Comment: Have you review the license and permissions of the installed package?

Comment: I have seen similar cases in the past wherein you have to Uninstall the Deployment Manager Installed Package and then try to re-install to fix the issue. Please confirm if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manage multiple Marketing Cloud orgs, and we use Deployment Manager on all of them. I am getting the same error on one org, while all others are fine. I've not yet been able to identify a difference between the orgs that work and the one that doesn't.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that has not worked. Licensing has been reviewed and updated, but that also failed to resolve the issue.

Chrome throws the error above, while Firefox throws this error:  "This integration is not eligible to use the /v2/token endpoint because the integration was created in a legacy package. To obtain a token for this integration, use the /v1/requestToken endpoint."

I'm continuing to research, but hopefully this information helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was on the following page from developer.salesforce.com:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm

This quote may be relevant, "While customers on S1 through S10 can continue to use the legacy endpoints, we recommend that you use the tenant-specific Marketing Cloud endpoints for improved performance."

The org I'm having issues with is on S12.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue o S12.
The solution that worked for me was using **PACKAGE MANAGER**.  It is the newer and better version of Deployment Manager and should already be configured in your org in the top navigation menu.